# `Error while updating property 'region' of a view managed by: AIRMap null Longitude'

Tags: google-maps, react-native

I want to make a map where user can select his current location as well and can select location from other than his current location...But i am getting this error ... "Error while updating property 'region' of a view managed by: AIRMap  null Longitude"......Here i am attaching my Map Class code too ...Please help me

```
 import React from 'react';

    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

    import { View, StyleSheet, Animated, Platform, UIManager, TouchableOpacity, Text, ViewPropTypes } from 'react-native';


    import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';


    import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';

    import axios from 'axios';

    import Events from 'react-native-simple-events';

    import MapView from 'react-native-maps';


    import AutoCompleteInput from './AutoCompleteInput'

    const PLACE_DETAIL_URL = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json';
    const DEFAULT_DELTA = { latitudeDelta: 0.015, longitudeDelta: 0.0121 };


    export default class Map extends React.Component {

     static propTypes = {
        apiKey:"AIzaSyCqDF-mH8qkUQ4z0qB1exxxxxxI0FYRACs",

        initialLocation: PropTypes.shape({
          latitude: PropTypes.number,
          longitude: PropTypes.number,
        }).isRequired,
        markerColor: PropTypes.string,

        actionButtonStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
        actionTextStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
        actionText: PropTypes.string,
        onLocationSelect: PropTypes.func,
        debounceDuration: PropTypes.number,

        components: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
      };

      static defaultProps = {
        markerColor: 'black',

        actionText: 'DONE',

        onLocationSelect: () => ({}),

        debounceDuration: 300,

        components: [],

      };

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        if (Platform.OS === 'android')
     {
          UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && 
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
        }
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        Events.listen('InputBlur', this.constructor.displayName, this._onTextBlur);
        Events.listen('InputFocus', this.constructor.displayName, this._onTextFocus);
        Events.listen('PlaceSelected', this.constructor.displayName, this._onPlaceSelected);
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
        Events.rm('InputBlur', this.constructor.displayName);
        Events.rm('InputFocus', this.constructor.displayName);
        Events.rm('PlaceSelected', this.constructor.displayName);
      }

      state = {
        inputScale: new Animated.Value(1),
        inFocus: false,
        region: {
          ...DEFAULT_DELTA,
          ...this.props.initialLocation,

        },
      };

      _animateInput = () => {
        Animated.timing(this.state.inputScale, {
          toValue: this.state.inFocus ? 1.2 : 1,
          duration: 300,
        }).start();
      };

      _onMapRegionChange = region => {
        this._setRegion(region, false);
        if (this.state.inFocus) {
          this._input.blur();
        }
      };

      _onMapRegionChangeComplete = region => {
        this._input.fetchAddressForLocation(region);
      };

      _onTextFocus = () => {
        this.state.inFocus = true;
        this._animateInput();
      };

      _onTextBlur = () => {
        this.state.inFocus = false;
        this._animateInput();
      };

      _setRegion = (region, animate = true) => {
        this.state.region = { ...this.state.region, ...region };
        if (animate) this._map.animateToRegion(this.state.region);
      };

      _onPlaceSelected = placeId => {
        this._input.blur();
        axios.get(`${PLACE_DETAIL_URL}?key=${this.props.apiKey}&placeid=${placeId}`).then(({ data }) => {
          let region = (({ lat, lng }) => ({ latitude: lat, longitude: lng }))(data.result.geometry.location);
          this._setRegion(region);
        });
      };

      _getCurrentLocation = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
          let location = (({ latitude, longitude }) => ({ latitude, longitude }))(position.coords);
          this._setRegion(location);
        });
      };

      render() {
        let { inputScale } = this.state;
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView
              ref={mapView => (this._map = mapView)}
              style={styles.mapView}
              region={this.state.region}
              showsMyLocationButton={true}
              showsUserLocation={false}
              onPress={({ nativeEvent }) => this._setRegion(nativeEvent.coordinate)}
              onRegionChange={this._onMapRegionChange}
              onRegionChangeComplete={this._onMapRegionChangeComplete}
            />
            <Entypo
              name={'location-pin'}
              size={30}
              color={this.props.markerColor}
              style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
            />
            <View style={styles.fullWidthContainer}>
              <AutoCompleteInput
                ref={input => (this._input = input)}
                apiKey={this.props.apiKey}
                style={[styles.input, { transform: [{ scale: inputScale }] }]}
                debounceDuration={this.props.debounceDuration}
                components={this.props.components}
              />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[styles.currentLocBtn, { backgroundColor: this.props.markerColor }]}
              onPress={this._getCurrentLocation}
            >
              <MaterialIcons name={'my-location'} color={'white'} size={25} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={[styles.actionButton, this.props.actionButtonStyle]}
              onPress={() => this.props.onLocationSelect({ ...this.state.region, address: this._input.getAddress() })}
            >
              <View>
                <Text style={[styles.actionText, this.props.actionTextStyle]}>{this.props.actionText}</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            {this.props.children}
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use showsUserLocation props you need to add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission into your AndroidManifest.xml

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

hope it will help!

Comment: it is already added to my AndroidManifest file , Respected madam

Comment: If the permission will not be there, he won't reach this point of getting error.

Answer (score 0):

first set default region so that it wont crash on start.

```
const LATITUDE = 40.665364;
const LONGITUDE = -74.213377;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0043;
const LONGITUDE_DELTA = 0.0034;
```

set region props default value this.state.region which is null, which cause this error try adding its default value in state. like this

```
state = {
    region:{
        latitude: LATITUDE,
        longitude: LONGITUDE,
        latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
        longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
      }
}



<MapView
          ref={map => (this.map = map)}
          customMapStyle={uber_style}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: LATITUDE,
            longitude: LONGITUDE,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA
          }}
          region={this.state.region}
          onMapReady={this.onMapLayout}
          maxZoomLevel={this.state.maxZoomLevel}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          loadingIndicatorColor="#e21d1d"
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: Metrics.screenWidth,
            height: Metrics.screenHeight
          }}
          showsBuildings={true}
          loadingEnabled={true}
          //   showsUserLocation={true}
          onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
        >
```

Comment: let me try this sir.

Comment: what are these lines here ??
 customMapStyle={uber_style},

   onMapReady={this.onMapLayout},

 maxZoomLevel={this.state.maxZoomLevel},

             provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE},

 onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete},

Comment: this code is showing only map interface after removing the above lines

Answer (score 0):

Below is my sample code:

```
 var coords = this.props.navigation.state.params.locationvalue; //getting location from props.
            try {
                this.map.animateToRegion({
                    ...this.state.locationArea,
                    latitude: coords.latitude,
                    longitude: coords.longitude
                });
                this.setState(prevState => {
                    return {
                        locationArea: {
                            ...prevState.locationArea,
                            latitude: coords.latitude,
                            longitude: coords.longitude
                        }
                    };
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("error map.animateRegion(): " + JSON.stringify(error))
            }
```

Here I was passing the wrong value of latitude and longitude when using this.map.animateToRegion method.

You can check that you are passing the exact value of latitude and longitude while using animateToRegion with MapView. I hope this solution helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was a `typo` error. Region `lat` and `long` are in a `string`. Also, it shouldn’t be `blank` or `undefined` .

You can use `Number` or `parseFloat` to parse.

```
 const LATITUDE = '70.664'; //type string
 const LONGITUDE = '-58.23077';
```

Fix to this is :

```
region:{
    latitude: parseFloat(LATITUDE), //or Number(LATITUDE)
    longitude: parseFloat(LONGITUDE),
    latitudeDelta: 0.02,
    longitudeDelta: 0.02,
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried the fix from https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/4842#issuecomment-1713357892 and it worked:

Create a patch file with the patch-package npm package.

Here are the steps:

Install patch package as a project dependency with

```
yarn add patch-package
```

Add the following to your package.json script section:

```
"postinstall": "patch-package"
```

Go to the node_modules/react-native-maps/android/build.gradle
update the file from

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:20.0.0"
```

to

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.0"
```

Create a patch file

```
npx patch-package react-native-maps --include "android/build.gradle"
```